# Loading a CSV into Core Data managed sqlite db

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, csv

I have a CSV file containing data.
I want to load it into a Core Data managed sqlite db.

I just ran one of the sample Core Data Xcode apps and noticed it created the db file.
I noticed table names all started with Z and the primary keys were stored in separate table so from this am I right in presuming that just importing the CSV data directly into the db using sqlite3 command line might mess up primary keys.

Do I need to write a program to read in the CSV line by line and then create objects for each row and persist them to the db.
Anyone got any code for this?
And can I write a desktop client to do this using Core Data. If so will the db be fine to use in IPhone core data app?

Can I then just include the prefilled db in my project and it will be deployed with the app correctly or is there something else I should do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`NSScanner`](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/11/writing-parser-using-nsscanner-csv.html) to read your CSV file into the `NSManagedObject` instances in your Core Data store.

Comment: I think that link you posted for NSScanner isn't working anymore :/

Comment: I added a currently live link.

Answer (score 5):

I have some categories on NSString for reading and writing CSV files from/to NSArrays.  I'll post them online and edit my answer with a link to it.

**edit**

They're online here:  http://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser