# Is it possible to import a csv file into a Core Date model

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Is it possible in core data to import CSV file?

Can anyone tell me how and what are the various ways?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499154/loading-a-csv-into-core-data-managed-sqlite-db

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about core data, but if you don't mind using a small library, [Wikipedia seems to list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV_application_support) [cCSVParse](http://michael.stapelberg.de/cCSVParse), which looks useful for this (the linked page is in German, the download link is somewhere in the middle).

Comment: basically i m doing this task in xcode for iphone Do you have any idea 

i appreciate your response.

Comment: Answer needs to refer to details about Core Data.